# LeetCode 146: LRU Cache (Go)

Tags: beginner, algorithm, object-oriented, programming-challenge, go

Posting my code for LeetCode's LRU Cache, if you'd like to review, please do so, thank you for your time!

#### Problem

> - Design and implement a data structure for Least Recently Used (LRU) cache. It should support the following operations: get and put.
> - get(key) - Get the value (will always be positive) of the key if the key exists in the cache, otherwise return -1.
> - put(key, value) - Set or insert the value if the key is not already present. When the cache reached its capacity, it should invalidate the
>   least recently used item before inserting a new item.
> - The cache is initialized with a positive capacity.
>
> Follow up:
>
> - Could you do both operations in O(1) time complexity?
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```
> LRUCache cache = new LRUCache( 2 /* capacity */ );
>
> cache.put(1, 1);  
> cache.put(2, 2);  
> cache.get(1);       // returns 1  
> cache.put(3, 3);    // evicts key 2  
> cache.get(2);       // returns -1 (not found)  
> cache.put(4, 4);    // evicts key 1  
> cache.get(1);       // returns -1 (not found)  
> cache.get(3);       // returns 3  
> cache.get(4);       // returns 4
> ```

#### Code

```
type LRUCache struct {
    head     *Node
    tail     *Node
    cache    map[int]*Node
    capacity int
}

type Node struct {
    prev *Node
    next *Node
    key  int
    val  int
}

func Constructor(capacity int) LRUCache {
    return LRUCache{capacity: capacity, cache: make(map[int]*Node)}
}

func (this *LRUCache) Get(key int) int {
    node, stored := this.cache[key]
    if !stored {
        return -1
    }

    this.Evict(node)
    this.Add(node)

    return node.val
}

func (this *LRUCache) Put(key int, val int) {
    node, stored := this.cache[key]
    if !stored {
        node = &Node{val: val, key: key}
        this.cache[key] = node
    } else {
        node.val = val
        this.Evict(node)
    }

    this.Add(node)
    if len(this.cache) > this.capacity {
        node = this.tail
        if node != nil {
            this.Evict(node)
            delete(this.cache, node.key)
        }
    }
}

func (this *LRUCache) Evict(node *Node) {
    if node == this.head {
        this.head = node.next
    }

    if node == this.tail {
        this.tail = node.prev
    }

    if node.next != nil {
        node.next.prev = node.prev
    }

    if node.prev != nil {
        node.prev.next = node.next
    }
}

func (this *LRUCache) Add(node *Node) {
    node.prev = nil
    node.next = this.head
    if node.next != nil {
        node.next.prev = node
    }

    this.head = node
    if this.tail == nil {
        this.tail = node
    }
}
```

#### Reference

Here is LeetCode's template:

```
type LRUCache struct {
    
}


func Constructor(capacity int) LRUCache {
    
}


func (this *LRUCache) Get(key int) int {
    
}


func (this *LRUCache) Put(key int, value int)  {
    
}


/**
 * Your LRUCache object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * obj := Constructor(capacity);
 * param_1 := obj.Get(key);
 * obj.Put(key,value);
 */
```

- [146. LRU Cache - Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/)
- [146. LRU Cache - Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/discuss/)